# Can't complete matlab installing

Tags: software-center, matlab

I am student interested in ubuntu. (or newbie coder)

I try to install matlab from **"Ubuntu Software Center"**

and, I see some dialog be written **"Can't find installed matlab"**.

So I close dialog **while installing**. (It's my mistake)

Even if I turn off computer,  when I turn on computer, It is not removed.

I try to **"sudo apt-get remove matlab"**. But that occur error.

(Occurred Error : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debconf/+bug/349469)

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you actually installed `matlab-support` from the software center. This is **NOT** Matlab. This package configures a pre-existing installation of Matlab. Only install this package if you already have Matlab from [MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/) installed.

It looks like there were problems with the installation of this package. To see which process is locking the file `config.dat`, type:

```
sudo fuser -v /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
```

It will result in output similar to:

```
root 2931 F.... frontend
```

The number is the process id of the process locking `config.dat`. Next kill this process:

```
sudo kill 2931
```

Except replace `2931` with the process id for your case. Now lets see if we can repair things:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge matlab-support
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If you are looking for a free alternative to Matlab, you should look into using [`octave`](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). The syntax and functionality is very similar to Matlab, but the GUI support is not as good.

Comment: Oh... thanks for your answer. But it is'nt help to me

Comment: @OSE: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly for me where simply using "sudo apt-get autoremove --purge matlab-support" previously failed, as the process was still running as you correctly deduced.

Comment: Thanks a lot! **Totally** solved my problem. Also, thanks yo your suggestion I am also exploring Octave now. Its basic but okay.